# drawing grid lines beween points in python

Tags: python

I have 6 points in the `(x,y)` plane: `x=[x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6]` and `y=[y1,y2,y3,y4,y5,y6]`

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt    
x = [0, 2, 4, 0, 2, 4, 0, 2, 4]
y = [0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 3, 7, 7, 7]

plt.scatter(x, y)
plt.show()
```

I want to between the points, draw entirely parallel lines on each axis `x,y`(like [photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W9uzA.png)). and how to hide x and y axis on diagram. I want to draw a 2D view of the beams and columns of 3 story building; does `matplotlib` bring me to my goal or should I go to other libraries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Absolutely `matplotlib` can do this. Take a look at their [Rectangle Patch](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.Rectangle.html#matplotlib.patches.Rectangle):

Example usage (you'll have to modify this to your needs):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot()

rect = patches.Rectangle(
    (0.1, 0.1),
    0.5,
    0.5,
    fill=False
)
ax.add_patch(rect)
fig.show()
```